# Web Analytics Connector only on whitelisted domains

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, web-analytics-connector

After enabling Web Analytics connector I have noticed some of our external links (not on our own website) break, is it possible to only allow associated parameters to be appended to "authorised/whitelisted" domains?

Comment: 1. Are these links output with ampscript or are they hardcoded in HTML?
2. Are you sure these external sites don't use redirects?
3. Can you post example of such link?

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easily automated way of doing so.

The following AMPScript can be used as the basis of a workaround to prevent the parameters from being added to a single link - but the logic behind using this vs, standard RedirectTo AmpScript needs to be built and maintained within your emails:

```
%%[ var @URL Set @URL = "http://www.salesforce.com"" 
]%% 
%%[ var @Link Set @Link = Concat('<a href=',v(@URL),' alias="Link">Link Test</a>') 
]%% 


%%=v(@Link)=%%
```